# R - Efficiently calculate the number of columns meeting a condition for each observation in a dataset

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to find a tidyverse-based programmatic approach to calculating the number of variables meeting a condition in a dataset. The data contains a row for each individual and a variable containing a code that describes something about that individual. I need to efficiently create a tally of how many times that variable code meets multiple sets of criteria. My current process uses dplyr's mutate along with row-wise summing within a tidyverse pipeline to create the required tally.

Other similar posts to this answer the question by summing rowwise, as I already do. In practice, this approach results in an extensive amount of code and slow processing since there are five variables, thousands of individuals, and a dozen criteria to tally separately.

Here is a demonstration of what I've tried so far. The desired output here is calculated as if the condition were for the code in the variables to match 20 or 24.

```
## Sample data and result

sample <- tibble(
  subjectNum = 1:10,
  var1 = c(20, 24, 20, 1, 24, 27, 7, 21, 20, 3),
  var2 = c(24, 20, 7, 19, 12,  8,  8, 10, 22, NA),
  var3 = c(NA, NA, 24, 20, NA, 20,  9,  3, 24, NA),
  desired_output = c(2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0)
)

sample_calc <- sample %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(output = sum(var1 %in% c(20, 24), var2 %in% c(20, 24), var3 %in% c(20, 24), na.rm= TRUE))

all(sample_calc$output == sample_calc$desired_output) # should return TRUE
```

The actual analysis requires conducting such a test for multiple sets of criteria that are available in a separate data file. It also requires the data structure to generally be maintained, so solutions using pivot_longer to count the variables fail as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use the vectorized `rowSums` by looping `across` the columns that `starts_with` 'var', create the condition within the loop and do the `rowSums` on the logical columns.  It should be more efficient than `rowwise` `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
sample %>% 
  mutate(output = rowSums(across(starts_with('var'),
      ~ .x %in% c(20, 24)), na.rm = TRUE))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 × 6
   subjectNum  var1  var2  var3 desired_output output
        <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>          <dbl>  <dbl>
 1          1    20    24    NA              2      2
 2          2    24    20    NA              2      2
 3          3    20     7    24              2      2
 4          4     1    19    20              1      1
 5          5    24    12    NA              1      1
 6          6    27     8    20              1      1
 7          7     7     8     9              0      0
 8          8    21    10     3              0      0
 9          9    20    22    24              2      2
10         10     3    NA    NA              0      0
```